# How to restrict Number Field default value set to '0' in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using Extjs 3.4, I have a grid where I use editor function and form of NumberField type.
Here is my scenario, when the user starts editing a number field and immediately clears it and navigating to next page makes the field value set to '0' with dirty flag set which i dont want.
So, please help me out in having the control over the cell edited and also get the value i updated in the cells.

Thanks in advance,
RK

Comment: share your code so far

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs, when we defined a `int` field in the model.Its **default value** is taken as **0**.We need to take help of `useNull` property in field with value as **true**:

```
{
            name: <fieldName>,
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },
```

Comment: Hi Ankit,I tried with 'useNull' property but it did not work. I can make it more clear, when an user starts editing an number field and immediately clears it off, without no value in the field, tab out to some other field and submit the form makes the field value to zero which the user do not want and basically user also can provide the field value set to zero and submit the form.                                                                                                     It could be more helpful if you assist me in getting control over the values as need to validate them.

Comment: Try ```allowNull: true```